# How to add emptyDir volume with medium = memory in openshift?

Tags: openshift

You can add an emptyDir volume to your pods by using

```
oc volume dc/registry --add
```

However, I want to specify the "medium: memory" to make this volume back by memory. How to set the medium for this volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
oc set volume dc/registry --add --source='{"emptyDir":{"medium":"Memory"}}'
```

Comment: Does this work with restricted scc?